# Ask permission for Geolocation using notifications API

Tags: html, geolocation, notifications

I am eager to know if I can ask permission for geolocation using the notification API(HTML5) and save it in the preferences(chrome) ??

Answer (score 0):

Notification API is for notification only. You can't have any interaction in notification.

The permission asking is done by the browser so there's no way you can skip it, so I don't think it's possible to find any workaround to use notification API for permission asking.